# Need Help Looping this when alphabet is input

Tags: java, validation, loops

```
            do{
                try{
                    System.out.println("Enter the no of People");  
                    child = input.nextInt();
                    if(child < 0){
                        System.out.println("Enter a Positive Value");
                    }
                }
                    catch(InputMismatchException e){
                        input.next();
                        System.out.println("(Invalid Input! Enter a numeric Value"); <---- Will give out the error if user enters a character
                    }
            }while(child < 0);
```

The program just ends after the error when user inputs alphabet
I need to loop it after it

Comment: sorry 
child = input.nextInt(); 
NOT a; 
sorry

Comment: What is the value of child before entering the do while? If it is 0 or if it is an instance variable, the loop will not continue looping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've not posted any answer to my question, here's a guess answer but I'm pretty sure the problem is the following :

The `child` variable has certainly a value of 0 or more when entering the loop. When trying to cast the `String` to an `int`, the value of `child` does not change of course and so the test is not fulfilled.

Here is a simple trick to use within your `catch` clause :

```
catch(InputMismatchException e){
    input.next();
    System.out.println("(Invalid Input! Enter a numeric Value");
    child = -1;
}
```

Just put `child` to less than `0` so that when you catch an exception, it will always loop back.